# Setting realm and issuer for web service at Runtime (windows azure ACS)

Tags: rest, azure, wif, acs

We have the scenario in our project,

We have Tenant-1 to Tenant-n which consume Restful Service S1. The tenants have a 1 to 1 relationship with IDP. Client has to federate the tenant UI through Restful Service using ACS with the help of tenant specific IDP configured in ACS at the time of onboarding.

Tenant-1 mapped to IdP1 (Eg: Yahoo)
Tenant-2 mapped to Idp2 (Eg: Google)

Restful Service returns a JavaScript as JSON, which is hosted within the Tenant’s Web UI. So if the tenant has already logged on to the Tenant UI using IDP specific to him via his own application, then for any requests from the tenant UI to Restful Service, the Restful service should federate to tenant specific IdP based on the partner information (mapping of tenant to IdP) configured during the onboarding process.

I am setting Realm in the Global.asax as shown below.

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public event EventHandler RedirectingToIdentityProvider;

    public override void Init()
    {
        FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectingToIdentityProvider += WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider;
    }

    void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider(object sender, RedirectingToIdentityProviderEventArgs e)
    {
        Tenant tenant = GetTenantDetails(subId); // Gets the tenant information from MetaData based on subscriptionId

        if (tenant != null)
        {
            e.SignInRequestMessage.Realm = tenant.Realm + "CMS/";
        }

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated += OnServiceConfigurationCreated;
    }

    private void OnServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, FederationConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (tenant != null)
        {
            e.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Issuer = tenant.Issuer;
            Uri uri = new Uri(tenant.Realm + "CMS/");
            if (!e.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Contains(uri))
                e.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(tenant.Realm + "CMS/"));
            e.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Realm = tenant.Realm + "CMS/";
        }            
    }
```

Further the Realm is set at the per request level too, as shown below.

```
public class MetaDataModule : IHttpModule
{

    private static string WSFederationAuthenticationModuleName = string.Empty;

    public void Init(HttpApplication httpContextApplication)
    {
        var requestWrapper = new EventHandler(DoSyncRequestWorkToGetTenantDetails);
        httpContextApplication.BeginRequest += requestWrapper;
    }

    private static void DoSyncRequestWorkToGetTenantDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var httpContextApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
        Tenant tenant = GetTenantDetails(); // Gets the tenant information from MetaData based on subscriptionId

        if (tenant != null)
        {
            WSFederationAuthenticationModule wsfed = (WSFederationAuthenticationModule)httpContextApplication.Modules["WSFederationAuthenticationModule"];
            wsfed.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Issuer = tenant.Issuer;
            Uri uri = new Uri(tenant.Realm + "CMS/");
            if (!wsfed.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Contains(uri))
                wsfed.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(tenant.Realm + "CMS/"));

            wsfed.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Realm = tenant.Realm + "CMS/";

            //FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Issuer = tenant.Issuer;
            //Uri uri = new Uri(tenant.Realm + "CMS/");
            //if (!FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Contains(uri))
            //    FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(tenant.Realm + "CMS/"));

            //FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Realm = tenant.Realm + "CMS/";
        }
    }
```

Please find the modules registered in the Web.config and the remaining part of WIF configuration too.

In spite of resetting the Realm for each request, the new value does not get assigned.

Client does not want their tenants to implement any authentication or federation related code from their end for this to work.

Please let me know if you can think of any solution to this issue with the help of Passive Federation.

Answer (score 0):

You should customize the realm in the Application_AuthenticateRequest method in your Global.asax.
Take a look at this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/cloud9/archive/2009/11/30/runtime-customization-of-microsoft.identitymodel-configuration.aspx).